# Unable to load network protocol stack

Tags: networking, embedded, protocols

I have the Ember desktop App in my PC and has the new Thread networking protocol stack software provided by Silicon Labs.

I'm trying to load the stack software into the ember development kit. But it always says unable to load the stack. Can anyone have any idea of why it's unable to load? I'm unable to figure out what the exact problem is.

Comment: Can you add the *verbatim* error?

Comment: Your current Ember Desktop version (3.3.1937) is out-dated. Please upgrade to the new version.

Comment: Don't write this as comment, [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/38303686/edit) your question to include this. And: Why aren't you upgrading your Ember desktop?